# haskell - takeWhile hangs when given a infinite list of primes

Tags: haskell

So, I'm working on a PE problem, and it's necessary to have a list of primes. So I do things the Haskell way and define an infinite list of primes, like so:

```
primes = 1 : 2 : filter isPrime [3,5..]
```

I was wondering why the program, which looked pretty fast to me, was taking forever on small numbers. Then I tried this:

```
*Main> takeWhile (<10) primes
[1,2
```

It doesn't even finish printing the list, and then it just hangs there. I'm sure this is just a silly beginner mistake, since I've only been working with Haskell for a few months (I come from the Lisp world).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess your `isPrime` function isn't working as you think since you have included 1 as a prime number, which it is not by definition.

Comment: since it works fine when using e.g. `filter (>5)` instead of `filter isPrime`, the issue is most probably in your `isPrime` function

Comment: Oh. You're right. it just returns false always. LOL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither `takeWhile` nor `filter` know anything about their arguments. `filter` will keep applying `isPrime` to the elements of its infinite list, not knowing that it will never produce a non-empty list, and `takeWhile` will keep asking for more values, not knowing that `filter` will never return a value greater than or equal to 10.

The solution, of course, is to provide a correct definition of `isPrime`.